# Why places api not searching for multiple places types?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

In my andorid app I have task to show some hot spot points around current location of user. So i am using this api from Google https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json? & my complete URL looks like this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=30.6970157,76.6875601&types=gym|cafe|schools|airport|lawyer&radius=5000&key=

but this api is showing result only for the first defined key viz: gym in this case. It seems backend is ignoring the other types (cafe|schools etc.). Can anybody guide me what i am doing wrong here?? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid no one can help you, you haven't provided any code. We can't say what you've done wrong if you dont show us. Edit the post and include relevant code.

Comment: @LieForBananas look some one has helped. Cheers...

Comment: There is no need to mock. I simply tried to help you by advising you to add some code because it attracts people and avoids downvotes. And just a side note, the downvote that you have is not mine.

Comment: @LieForBananas actually I don't understand why Standard Network code is required for understanding my question. Code can be a RETROFIT or VOLLEY Code BLOCK requesting an Api and consuming the Api responses. Code have nothing to do with it. I just want multiple POI from places api and as got confused by this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935763/getting-list-of-poi-from-google-places-api 
& thanks for not downvoting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nearby search does **not** have a `types` parameter. There once was, but this has been deprecated.

You have a `type` parameter but it can not contain more than one type.

> `type` — Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored).

Please refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=en#PlaceSearchRequests) for an up to date list of optional parameters.

Comment: Ok.I am afraid as many answers on stack overflow for Getting POI from Google places are suggesting that URL with piped symbols.Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935763/getting-list-of-poi-from-google-places-api
or search how to get multiple POI from places api.

Comment: you have any suggestions Which api or URL should I use to get the multiple types of POI(Place of Interest) from Google Places?

Comment: You can make one request per type.